# How to show a sidebar in all pages in mvc4 except 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

We currently have a site which has a section LatestNews, required:false defined in the layout
and all views  except two have the section which have the same call RenderPartial("ShowLatestNews")

Is there a better way to do this ? i.e. follow the DRY principle - define it in one place and hide/not use it in those 2 views only ?

UPDATE -

currently the layout is dynamically selected from a dbconfig based on user
Ideally we don't want to switch layout based on say controller and action combination

Comment: So you have a section and a partial? The reason to use `RenderPartial` is to componentize so that the individual views can dictate if they want that partial or not. Another option is to use multiple layouts if the rest of the site is being designed that way.

Comment: @Nate updated the question, yes it's not very straightforward hence my call to help from the experts :)

Comment: Personally I believe your approaching this the wrong way (unless I'm misinterpreting) I think you want to keep your controllers dictating what shows up in the views (user specified data) - Not the view itself, the only time I would have the view decide what it contains is for styling or gui stuff. I'll post an answer later busy atm.

Comment: @Nate it's a matter of style i suppose, in our case the controller dictates the specific view info and the sidebars are rendered independently without the controller having to know about that, i understand that doesn't work for anyone but we like the separation of concerns here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might now be the most eloquent solution but it's simple. In your layout page use this code for your partial:

```
@if (ViewBag.HideSection == null)
{
    @Html.RenderPartial("ShowLatestNews")
}
```

Now in the 2 controller actions you DON'T want the partial to render add this:

```
ViewBag.HideSection = true;
```

It will only hide the partial in those places you specify something in the ViewBag. It isn't evaluating true or false, just the presence of the property.

Answer (score 1):

There are really a ton of different directions this question opens up, a lot of these paths are dictated by the current design.

While others are cut and paste solutions

---

Lets say currently that you have two pages that are completely different from the master layout for the website, but are similar to each other (ex admin pages) or pages that may have the same layout for other 'forseeable' pages. Then I would recommend to change your layout for these pages - Diversifying each layout for their separate uses:

An Admin Page

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml"; 
}
```

A Regular Page

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

But now lets say that You/I/Whoever really just want these pages to be apart of the main layout but need them to be a Little different based on some information (ex admin, VIP tabs)
Strange the idea changes a little here, do we want the Controller to decide what to do or does the View already have this information... The data could ideally be put in a ViewModel or the ViewBag or Session data - again depends :)

By User - HTTP Context (cut & paste solution...)

```
<div id="specific-content">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("admin")) <!--RoleProvider-->
    {
        <div>My Admin Content!</div>
        <!--In your case render something (or not)!-->
        @{ Html.RenderPartial(...); }
    }
    else
    {
        <div>I'm not special :( </div>
    }
</div>
```

Or instead of putting the above code in the layout or on a page put it directly into a `Partial`

Theirs also one more that I was thinking of, and that is to redirect to a page if the user is a certain person, which I'm not a big fan of - stick to layouts and the `User` in the view.

These are the simpler ideas that I had in mind, hope that helped!